# Keep hyphens unless at the end of a word with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to load a textfile into my java program. I have thus written the following regex expression:

`lineWords = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\- ]", " ").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");`

This generally works very well to preserve hyphenated words but one of the words in the input file ends with a hyphen (I unfortunately can't control this). I've been looking for a way to preserve hyphens within words but eliminate them if they're at the end of the word. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us some expected and unexpected string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep hyphens unless at the end of a word , you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Either match any char except the ones listed in the character class or match an hyphen and use lookarounds asserting what is on the left is a word character and what is on the right is not a non whitespace char.

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z -]|(?<=\w)-(?!\S))
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^a-zA-Z -]` Match any char except the listed
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=\w)-(?!\S)` Assert what on the left is a word char and assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jgFqsO/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/C8MATt)

In Java

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z -]|(?<=\\w)-(?!\\S))
```

For example

```
String line = "this is a test $%$ test- test-test and -test ()";
String[] lineWords = line.replaceAll("(?:[^a-zA-Z -]|(?<=\\w)-(?!\\S))", " ").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineWords));
```

Output

```
[this, is, a, test, test, test-test, and, -test]
```

Comment: Question. What is the purpose of the space in the character class? After the A-Z before the hyphen.

A-Z -

Comment: @MikeScott The character class is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) Adding the space excludes the space from begin matched. See the matches here without adding the space https://regex101.com/r/qopXJx/1 If you want to exclude whitespace chars for example, you can add `\s` instead of a mere space.

Answer (score 1):

```java
      String line = "a-b c-d- e-f g-e r- st-u-";

      System.out.println(line);
      line = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).map(
            s -> s.replaceAll("-$", "")).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
      System.out.println(line);
```

Prints

```
a-b c-d- e-f g-e r- st-u-
a-b c-d e-f g-e r st-u
```

If you want to leave the line as separate words, then just do this.

```java
      String [] words = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).map(
            s -> s.replaceAll("-$", "")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
String str = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\- ]", " ").toLowerCase();
str = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '-' ? str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) : str;
lineWords = str.split("\\s+");
```

A quick demo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab7BTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "This word-list contains a word ending with -";
        String str = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\- ]", " ").toLowerCase();
        str = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '-' ? str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) : str;
        String []lineWords = str.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineWords));

        line = "This word-list contains a word ending with hyphen";
        str = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\- ]", " ").toLowerCase();
        str = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '-' ? str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) : str;
        lineWords = str.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineWords));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[this, word-list, contains, a, word, ending, with]
[this, word-list, contains, a, word, ending, with, hyphen]
```